# node.js - sending regex to server

Tags: regex, node.js, mongodb

I've created a client side mongodb interface to talk to server side mongodb.
it's very similar to the mini-mongo implemented in the meteor. 
here is an example:

```
model.find({"field": /search/}).exec(function(err, model){
    construct(model);
});
```

now normally everything works fine except when I use the regex.
and I know what's the problem but I cannot fix it.
the problem, as you have guessed it, is when the regex /regexParameter/ when sent by ajax to server, is converted to "/regexParameter/" and the single quotes(or double) make the regex a normal string.
in the server I have something like this:

```
var findObject = req.query.findObject // {"field": "/search/"} :(
req.models[config.table]
   .find(findObject)
   .exec(function(err, model){
        return res.json({
            error: err,
            result: model,
        });
   });
```

is there anything I can do to make this work without writing like 100 of lines of code that iterates through each of the findObject and matches every string for a regex...?
Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right - you cannot pass *RegExp* objects between client and server because during serialization they are converted to strings.

**Solution?** (or perhaps - a workaround)

Use `$regex` operator in your queries, so you don't need to use *RegExp* objects.

So this:

```
{
  field: /search/
}
```

Becomes this:

```
{
  field: {
    $regex: 'search'
  }
}
```

Or, giving a case-insensitive search example:

```
{
  field: {
    $regex: 'search',
    $options: 'i'
  }
}
```

(instead of `field: /search/i`)

Read more about `$regex` syntax [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) (including about some of its [restrictions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#syntax-restrictions)).